# ul first and last li to fill the screen

Tags: css, sass

I want to make something like this in the image. 
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sePbC.png)

It's not gonna be the number of li as it is on the image because it's a dynamic value. I want the ul centered and then the first and last li to fill the entire screen. Also, I can't use flex or flexbox to achieve this because of browser compatibilities

Any ideas or help? Thanks!

Comment: ..but flexbox can do this. Try that.

Comment: What have you already tried? And have you explored `flex-box` solutions? Include your html and css in a code snippet so we have a better idea of how far you've come and how far you still need to go.

Comment: I've tried with table and table-cells. Flexbox isn't compatible with some versions of the internet explorer and I need to have it work on those versions.

Comment: Check my answer may be it will help you.

Comment: @JoaoLopes Helpful info - update your question to include it, it may be missed in the comments.

Comment: @LKG thanks for your solution, it works as I wanted but I can't use flex, however, I'll save it for future reference. Thanks

Comment: I posted another way to get it pls check updated answer. but first one using flex is good one i think.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul class="wide-list">
  <li>item...</li>
  <li>item...</li>
    ...
  <li>item...</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.wide-list li:first-child {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wide-list li:last-child {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

No need for extra classes or IDs, more items can be added dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

## HTML

```
<ul class="centeredUL">
   <li class="firstItem"></li>
    ...
   <li class="lastItem"></li>
</ul>
```

## css

```
.centeredUL{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
.firstItem{
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.lastItem{
    float:right;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```